# Prisma v2: generate a .graphql file to edit with?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, prisma

I'm building a graphql server (with `apollo-server`) on an existing postgresql db (**I cannot modify the db tables**).

Prisma can introspect the db and generate a `schema.prisma` file containing all db tables. To implement the graphql server, I need to define graphql types and queries and mutations manually.

With Prisma v1, this `prisma.yml` can generate a graphql file.

```
generate:
  - generator: graphql-schema
  output: ./generated/prisma.graphql
```

For Prisma v2, is there any way to generate a graphql file from `schema.prisma`?

Then I can modify the graphql file by removing some types that do not needed to be exposed to front, and create queries and mutations by myself.

Comment: Same problem. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

prisma2 is an orm unlike prisma1 so you can use the [nexus-plugin-prisma](https://nexusjs.org/docs/plugins/prisma/overview) library to autogenerate your GraphQL types and resolvers from the Prisma schema

Comment: There's also [typegraphql-prisma](https://typegraphql.com/docs/prisma.html)

Answer (score 0):

Prisma 2 is just an ORM unlike Prisma 1 that had a GraphQL layer. So you would need external libraries like this to autogenerate a GraphQL file. You can check out [TypeGraphQL](https://typegraphql.com/docs/prisma.html) that does this.